# 'ImageFileDescriptor' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to iterate through the images in my categories but I'm getting `'ImageFileDescriptor' object has no attribute 'objects'` error

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="category")
    category_description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, default=1)

    def get_image_path(self, filename):
        gallery_path = os.path.abspath(
            os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.slug))
        if not os.path.isdir(gallery_path):
            os.mkdir(gallery_path)
        return os.path.join(gallery_path, filename)

    gallery = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)

    def create_directory(self):
        gallery_path = os.path.abspath(
            os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.slug))
        if not os.path.isdir(gallery_path):
            os.mkdir(gallery_path)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.create_directory()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.slug))
        # os.rmdir(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.slug))
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_title
```

**views.py**

```
def category_detail_view(request, slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
    context = {
        "gallery": Category.gallery.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'main/category_detail.html', context)
```

**category_detail.html**

```
{% for image in gallery %}
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <a href="{{ image.url }}"> <img src="{{ image.url }}" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" width="304" height="236"/>
      </a>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

For some reason creating galleries in Django has been difficult for me. It seems as if there is no standard way that most people are doing this. Even if I get this to work, I don't see how one could manage the uploaded images from the admin panel. ex upload delete arrange etc

If you could shed some light on this for me that would be awesome

Comment: There are some weird misconceptions here. Why have you done `Category.gallery.objects`? And even more, why do you think you can iterate at all? A category only has one "gallery", which is a single image field not a collection.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Okay it looks like I need a new approach. What would you recommend I do? Before I was able to manually display images when I'd do `gallery = os.listdir(settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: Well it feels like you need a separate Image model with a foreign key to Category.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I thought about that but would it be okay to have hundreds on instances of an `Image` model? I was hoping to be able to manage galleries and carousels inside specific categories from the admin

Comment: Yes of course, why wouldn't it be?